# Simulating enter key java

Tags: java

I am trying to get input from the user without making the user press the ENTER key. The ENTER press is simulated after 2 seconds the user is prompted for input.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.io.*;
public class test
{
    private String str = "";

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
                // Code for SimulateEnterKeyPress goes here
        }
    };

    public void getInput() throws Exception
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule( task, 2000 );

        System.out.println( "Input a string within 2 seconds: " );
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
        str = in.readLine();

        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println( "You have entered: "+ str );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
                (new test()).getInput();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
                System.out.println( e );
        }
    }
}
```

How to simulate ENTER keypress in Java?

P.S. Is there any other simple alternative method for above possible.

Comment: you can use a `java.awt.Robot` for this `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

Comment: i´m just gonig to note that the `Robot` class doesn´t bother which application or if an application is active, it will press the `Enter` key nontheless if you implement it.

Comment: Thanks. I just went through the Oracle docs about the Robot class. It was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `java.awt` package you will find the class `Robot`. Instantiate an object of this class and use the `keyPress(int keyCode)`-method.